# getting datetime value from Phpyadmin in this manner 1989-10-04 00:00:00.000000

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I am getting value of DOB field and its object of array from DB like this.

echo $value->dob;

got output like this 1989-10-04 00:00:00.000000

I want to display value like  04-10-1989 only.

Please help me out

Comment: You can use the PHP methods of [strtotime](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), or you can use the mysql method of [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: This can be solved in different ways, what did you try so far? This might help us to give out the answer that best fits your needs...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Comment: Thanks @aynber I fixed it just because of you. I got frustrated while doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example

```
$dob = '1989-10-04 00:00:00.000000';

$new_dob = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($dob));

echo $new_dob;
```

produces

```
04-10-1989
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this 
$dob = 'your database date value';

$dob1= date('d-m-Y', strtotime($dob));

echo $dob1;